# Details of the Realization of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes

A well known example of a strict-sense stationary random process is along the lines of
$X_t = \sin(2\cdot \pi\cdot f\cdot t + \theta)$  where $\theta$ is some random variable, usually  $\theta\sim \text{Uniform}(0,2\pi)$. f is just a fixed frequency > 0. I am slightly confused about how a realization of this process looks like. So we have

$X_t(\omega) = \sin(2\cdot \pi\cdot f\cdot t  + \theta(\omega))$ and it all comes down how exactly such an $\omega$ looks like. In this example I assume $\omega$ is a scalar and is "drawn" before the start of the random process such that $\theta(\omega)$ is constant with respect to $t$. The randomness then stems from not knowing beforehand which $\omega$ would be drawn. However, after the random process has "started" $\theta(\omega)$ is just a constant phase. Do I understand this correctly? An alternative would be to draw to have $\omega = \omega_t$, i.e. a new $\omega$ for every $t$.

edit: I added the meaning of f.

Comment: What is $f$ in the definition of $X_t$?

Comment: Yes, each $X_t$ is essentially the same sine wave displaced left or right

Comment: Thank you. So does "essentially the same sine wave displaced left or right" mean that, e.g. for one realization we have $X_t(\omega_1) = sin(2\cdot\pi\cdot f \cdot t + 0.2\pi)$ for all t and for another realization we have $X_t(\omega_2) = sin(2\cdot\pi\cdot f \cdot t + 1.32\pi)$? With $\theta(\omega_1) = 0.2\pi$ and $\theta(\omega_2) = 1.32\pi$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!